# Facebook credits with much higher payout on Mobile Phone option

Tags: facebook, facebook-credits

I'm developing a Facebook app and I sell a digital product for 10 credits. In the credit card payment, the price is 1$, but in the mobile phone option the price is 2.5$. This is true for another credits amount. Let's say that I sell a product for 20 credits, the credit card price is 2$ but the mobile phone price is 4.7$.

Is this usual? It seems to makes no sense at all, as the price is more than 100% higher when paying by mobile phone!

Why is this happening?

Many thanks

P.S.: I'm portuguese, client of Vodafone.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is normal. Payment by mobile phone comes with *much* higher fees than just about any other form of payment processing I know of, and typically a good chunk of those fees get passed on to the consumer.

What to do about it? One possibility (maybe the *only* possibility) would be to add a layer of abstraction - create an in-app virtual currency, purchased with credits, which the user can exchange for your product. However, if you don't plan to offer many different items that could be more trouble than it's worth, or create an unnecessarily complicated/confusing user experience.